The difference between along and next to
Along- in a line next to something.
Could I then say "I parked along the other car"?
The meaning is I think similar to using "next to" or "alongside" yet I'm not sure if it work because normally it is "we walked along the beach or the street" so long objects.

Your example isn't idiomatically acceptable. It must be I parked alongside the other car (or next to).

@FumbleFingers why? It need to be something longer like a street?

That is not a good definition of "along".

Basically, the word 'along' is not a point concpet but a line concept: along the road, along the river, along the corridor, along both sides of the river, along the street, along the line

If you walk along the path, you're placing your feet on the path itself. If you walk alongside the path,  your feet never touch the actual path, because you're walking near, beside (but not on) the path.

First, here are some dictionary definitions:

along: in a line matching the length or direction of (walking along the road)
also : at a point or points on (a house along the river)
alongside: along the side : in parallel position

Obviously they're related; "along" even appears in the definition of "alongside." One way to see the difference is to think about the word "long" inside both of them. "Along" is useful when you have "a... long... line." Okay, it doesn't have to be very long; you could move your finger "along the line" of text on a page. But the point is that it is "linear"; it's about lines. It's not about width; you don't sail a boat "along" the sea (you sail accross the sea), but you might sail it "along" the shoreline. Note, you can use "all" with "along," like "there were cars parked all along the street." You can't say "all alongside" this way.
Meanwhile, "alongside" has "side" in it. It literally means "along the side of." It's not just about a line, it's about shapes, usually two shapes, and about how they're positioned next to each other. Here, I'll draw a rough picture of two rectangles:

Each rectangle has a long side. And the long sides are next to each other. Note, this is just a handy way to remember the difference; you might still use "alongside" if the shapes were squares, or maybe if the short ends of the were next to each other (though other phrases like "end to end" might be more likely for that).
So: you suggested that "along" means "in a line next to something." A better definition would be "in a line following something that is long like a line." As you can see, that works for walking "along" a beach or a street, but not so well for parking a car; "next to" or "alongside" are better for that. Though, if you used "along" I'm sure your meaning would be understood.
